# Pronunciation of "gibberish" and "direction"?

Tags: pronunciation

I heard two different pronunciations for both *gibberish* and *direction*.

I heard the *di* in *direction* uttered as both the *di* /daɪ/ in *die* and as the *di* /dɪ/ in *did*.

I have also heard the *g* in *gibberish* pronounced like the *G* /g/ in *Greece* and the *J* /dʒ/ in *Jesus*.

So what should the correct pronunciation be each of the word? Pronunciation of both of them is highly disputed.

Comment: These are two unrelated questions, so they should probably be asked separately.

Comment: @Kit, Did not want to make two questions out of it; then both of them would produce typical tiny answers.

Comment: Downvoters please comment and let me know if anything is wrong.

Comment: @Mistu4u I didn't downvote, but I think Kit has a good point.  What are the odds that someone will want to find out the answers to both of these questions at the same time?  Fairly slim, I'd say.

Comment: @snailplane, Fair enough. But like I said before I do not see a good point of making two questions out of it. I added these two words at a time because I thought both of these words pronunciations are highly controversial. That's why. Anyways I have nothing to do if people want to down-vote.

Comment: If anyone's interested, [there's more on the origin and pronunciation of "gibberish" here](http://blog.oup.com/2008/12/gibberish/). But as OP obviously recognises, soft/hard g are both used. It's not up to ELL to say which is "correct".

Comment: Shame you did not split the question into two separate questions

Comment: Is pronunciation of gibberish really "highly disputed"? I've *never* heard it said with a hard "g".

Comment: Why has it been multi-downvoted? It's a valid question.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never heard *gibberish* pronounced with a hard *g*, but maybe I just need to travel more. As Barrie showed in his answer, both pronunciations are listed in the OED. As for the *direction* dichotomy, you see that sort of variant in English **quite often**. Pronunciation variations fall into a few different categories, such as:

- where the vowel of a word can be pronounced one of at least two ways, as in [*process*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/process)
- where the accented syllable of a word shifts, as in [*redress*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/redress)
- where the word is pronounced differently depending the word's part of speech, as in [*record*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/record)

(Those examples only cover officially recognized pronunciation differences, and don't account for local accents and dialects, or international differences.)

There's even an English idiom that goes:

> You say *tomato*, I say *tomato*

which looks oddly nonsensical, unless you spell it phonetically:

> You say təmātō, I say təmätō

The saying essentially means, "I guess we see this matter differently, but that doesn't mean one of us has to be wrong."

Answer (score 5):

The Oxford English Dictionary shows both /ˈdʒɪbərɪʃ/ and /ˈɡɪbərɪʃ/ for *gibberish*. That is, the initial consonant is found both as the ‘j’ in *Jim* and as the ‘g’ in *gas*. As a speaker of British English, I always pronounce it the first way.

*Direction* is also given with two pronunciations for the first syllable: /dɪˈrɛkʃən/ and /daɪ-/. That is, as the vowel sound in ‘did’ and as the vowel sound in ‘die’. I probably pronounce it most of the time the second way. *Dairy* is pronounced /ˈdɛərɪ/, rhyming with *fairy*. *Deify* is pronounced /ˈdiːɪfaɪ/, the first two syllables rhyming with ‘see if’. Have you really heard the first syllable of *direction* pronounced in either of those ways?

Comment: Yes, did and die are fair enough. They make a lot more sense than my current examples.I would change my examples accordingly.

Comment: I pronounce *deify* /ˈdeɪɪfaɪ/ (day-i-fy, the IPA looks odd with two ɪ in it like that). I expect that's yet more influence from my Latin classes coming out.

Comment: @Andrew Leach. I think I do too, but was merely reporting the pronunciation given in the OED. In any case, neither seems a likely way to pronounce the first syllable of 'direction.

Comment: I always pronounce it the first way, and I'm a speaker of American English.  Has the latter pronunciation died out, I wonder?

Comment: @snailplane. So do I, and I don't recall ever hearing /ˈɡɪbərɪʃ/.

Answer (score 3):

English pronunciation isn't standard around the world. It isn't even standard in a given region. There are always native speakers (and non-native speakers) who have idiosyncratic pronunciations. The Macmillan online says "[gibberish](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/gibberish)" is pronounced with initial [dz] as in "jet". It gives two pronunciations for "[direction](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/direction)". But this is a question that can be answered by looking at a good dictionary.